# Asyncio worker that handles N jobs at a time?

Tags: python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make an `asyncio` worker class that will consume jobs from a job queue and process up to `N` jobs in parallel. Some jobs may queue additional jobs. When the job queue is empty and the worker finishes all of its current jobs, it should end.

I'm still struggling with `asyncio` conceptually. Here is one of my attempts, where `N=3`:

```
import asyncio, logging, random

async def do_work(id_):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
    return id_

class JobQueue:
    ''' Maintains a list of all pendings jobs. '''
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self._max_id = 10
        for id_ in range(self._max_id):
            self._queue.put_nowait(id_ + 1)

    def add_job(self):
        self._max_id += 1
        self._queue.put_nowait(self._max_id)

    async def get_job(self):
        return await self._queue.get()

    def has_jobs(self):
        return self._queue.qsize() > 0

class JobWorker:
    ''' Processes up to 3 jobs at a time in parallel. '''
    def __init__(self, job_queue):
        self._current_jobs = set()
        self._job_queue = job_queue
        self._semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(3)

    async def run(self):
        while self._job_queue.has_jobs() or len(self._current_jobs) > 0:
            print('Acquiring semaphore...')
            await self._semaphore.acquire()
            print('Getting a job...')
            job_id = await self._job_queue.get_job()
            print('Scheduling job {}'.format(job_id))
            self._current_jobs.add(job_id)
            task = asyncio.Task(do_work(job_id))
            task.add_done_callback(self.task_finished)

    def task_finished(self, task):
        job_id = task.result()
        print('Finished job {} / released semaphore'.format(job_id))
        self._current_jobs.remove(job_id)
        self._semaphore.release()
        if random.random() < 0.2:
            print('Queuing a new job')
            self._job_queue.add_job()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
jw = JobWorker(JobQueue())
print('Starting event loop')
loop.run_until_complete(jw.run())
print('Event loop ended')
loop.close()
```

An excerpt of the output:

```
Starting event loop
Acquiring semaphore...
Getting a job...
Scheduling job 1
Acquiring semaphore...
Getting a job...
Scheduling job 2
Acquiring semaphore...
Getting a job...
Scheduling job 3
Acquiring semaphore...
Finished job 2 / released semaphore
Getting a job...
Scheduling job 4
...snip...
Acquiring semaphore...
Finished job 11 / released semaphore
Getting a job...
Finished job 12 / released semaphore
Finished job 13 / released semaphore
```

It appears to correctly process all jobs while processing no more than 3 jobs at any one time. However, the program hangs after the last job is finished. As indicated by the output, it appears to be hanging at `job_id = await self._job_queue.get_job()`. Once the job queue is empty, this coroutine will never resume, and the check to see if the job queue is empty (at the top of the loop) isn't reached again.

I've tried working around this in a number of ways but conceptually something just don't quite fit. My current WIP is passing some futures between the queue and the worker and then using some combination of `asyncio.wait(...)` on all of them, but it's getting ugly and I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of [queue.task_done](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.task_done) that indicates that a formerly enqueued task is complete. Then you can combine [queue.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.join) and [queue.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.get) using [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait): if `queue.join` finishes and `queue.get` doesn't, this means all the jobs have been completed.

See this example:

```
class Worker:

    def __init__(self, func, n=3):
        self.func = func
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(n)

    def put(self, *args):
        self.queue.put_nowait(args)

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            args = await self._get()
            if args is None:
                return
            asyncio.ensure_future(self._target(args))

    async def _get(self):
        get_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.queue.get())
        join_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.queue.join())
        await asyncio.wait([get_task, join_task], return_when='FIRST_COMPLETED')
        if get_task.done():
            return task.result()

    async def _target(self, args):
        try:
            async with self.semaphore:
                return await self.func(*args)
        finally:
            self.queue.task_done()
```

Comment: I really like this idea, but the `asyncio.wait()` is a bit awkward since it returns results in an unpredictable order. In this toy example the possible results are only `None` or `int`, so its easy to figure out which coroutine actually finished, but I think in practice it will be very cumbersome to figure out which coroutine finished first. `asyncio.gather()` makes a little more sense but it lacks the `return_when` parameter. Hmm...

Comment: @mehaase See my edit (note that `args` is a list of arguments to pass to `self.func`, or `None` if all the jobs have been completed).

Comment: Ahhhh, it seems so simple after I have seen the solution! Thank you.

Comment: the code fails, i get NameError: name 'coros' is not defined, and also it is not clear how to apply the code.

Comment: The `_get` function is missing a line: `coros = (get_task, join_task)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can timeout `get_job` with simple [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for). For example with 1s, and get back to the beginning of loop on timeout.

```
    async def run(self):
        while self._job_queue.has_jobs() or len(self._current_jobs) > 0:
            print('Acquiring semaphore...')
            await self._semaphore.acquire()
            print('Getting a job...')
            try:
                job_id = await asyncio.wait_for(self._job_queue.get_job(), 1)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                continue
            print('Scheduling job {}'.format(job_id))
            self._current_jobs.add(job_id)
            task = asyncio.Task(do_work(job_id))
            task.add_done_callback(self.task_finished)
```

Comment: +1 This is definitely the easiest & cleanest fix but it feels a bit like cheating. Instead of waiting for the event loop to tell me when to resume, I'm polling the job queue. (Well, a hybrid of polling and coroutines.)