# Asyncio worker class to handle parallel jobs

Tags: parallel-processing, queue, python-asyncio

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114528/asyncio-worker-that-handles-n-jobs-at-a-time#38120788) but I dont understand how to make the code work

```py
class Worker:

    def __init__(self, func, n=3):
        self.func = func
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(n)

    def put(self, *args):
        self.queue.put_nowait(args)

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            args = await self._get()
            if args is None:
                return
            asyncio.ensure_future(self._target(args))

    async def _get(self):
        get_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.queue.get())
        join_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.queue.join())
        await asyncio.wait(coros, return_when='FIRST_COMPLETED')
        if get_task.done():
            return task.result()

    async def _target(self, args):
        try:
            async with self.semaphore:
                return await self.func(*args)
        finally:
            self.queue.task_done()
```

I tried then:

```
def work(a1,a2): print('work done',a1,a2)
W = Worker(work,n=3)
W.put(1,2)
W.put(1,2)
W.put(1,2)
result = await W.run() # for Jupyter notebooks
# asyncio.run(W.run()) # for normal python
```

I get error:

```
NameError: name 'coros' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit, the linked solution confused me, and it didn't seem to work. So, I just rewrote the `Worker` class which hopefully now works for you:

```py
import asyncio

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, func, n=3):
        self.func = func
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(n)

    def put(self, *args):
        self.queue.put_nowait(args)

    async def run(self):
        tasks = []
        while True:
            try:
                args = self.queue.get_nowait()
            except asyncio.QueueEmpty:
                break
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(self.do_work(args)))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    async def do_work(self, args):
        async with self.semaphore:
            await self.func(*args)
```

This seems like a much simpler way to do it to me. Basically, this changes `Worker.run` to just start a task for each item in the queue, and each task must first acquire the semaphore before calling the provided work function. And then it finishes after all the work is done.

Here is the usage:

```py
async def work(a1, a2):
    print("Starting work...", a1, a2)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Finishing work...")


W = Worker(work, n=3)
W.put(1,2)
W.put(3,4)
W.put(5,6)
W.put(7,8)
W.put(9,10)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(W.run())


"""Output
Starting work... 1 2
Starting work... 3 4
Starting work... 5 6
Finishing work...
Finishing work...
Finishing work...
Starting work... 7 8
Starting work... 9 10
Finishing work...
Finishing work...
"""
```

It should be noted that you cannot use `asyncio.run` while also using `asyncio.Semaphore` this way, because `asyncio.run` always starts a new loop, while `asyncio.Semaphore(n)` sets its loop as the default loop before `asyncio.run` is called. This causes the semaphore to use a different loop than `Worker.run`.

So just using `asyncio.get_event_loop.run_until_complete` works fine because it uses the default loop (which the semaphore is expecting).

Comment: thanks a lot @ParkerD!!! is it also possible to do do asyncio multiprocessing with lets say 4 workers that each have a queue that can be called asynchronuosly?

Comment: There's certainly nothing that prevents you from creating multiple `Worker` instances and calling their `run` method asynchronously, as long as `run` is called from the same event loop the `Worker`s were initialized in